# how to make "in" with "subquery" in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sql :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT id FROM umi where pid=10)
```

how to write it in sequelize?

I know the code is not right,this is my code:

```
db.user.findAll({
where:{uid:[0,1,2]}
)}
```

I do not know how to replace the [0,1,2]

should I query twice? one is get the array and then query the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it with `sequelize.literal` :**

```
db.user.findAll({
    where:{
        uid: {
            $in : [sequelize.literal('SELECT id FROM umi where pid=10'))]
        }
    }
)}
```

**If you have set proper association** then this will also work :

```
db.user.findAll({
    include : [{
        model : umi
        where : { pid : 10 }
    }]
)};
```

Comment: Thankyou Can I use where.uid.$in=[sequelize.literal('SELECT id FROM umi where pid=10'))]?

Comment: @daotian, i think that's the first one option , you can use any of them.